# Google maps JS API - get the north west & south east bounds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with google maps javascript API and I need to get the bounds of the current viewport.
I tried to use `map.getBounds();` then `getNorthEast()...` etc. but the problem is that I need the North **West**, and the South **East** coordinates, not North East and South West.

Any way to get those bounds or "convert" the bounds that the API gives me to get North West and South East ?

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the sample below you can extract the coords for North, East, South, and West

and you can use North West , South East

```
    aNorth  =   map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();   
    aEast   =   map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
    aSouth  =   map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();   
    aWest   =   map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
```